# Git, non-fast-forward issue on master when working on a branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull

I am working on an branch, let's say it's `branch1.1`. I make several changes and just use 'git commit' to commit those changes. Then as I usually working on `master`, I do an `git push` to check in them. However such errors occurs:

```
To git@thoroughbred:flt/test.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@thoroughbred:flt/test.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

When I do a `git pull`, it is said that

```
'Already up-to-date'
```

How to resolve this issue? It seems that something changes on `master`, but I am on `branch1.1`, and the things I want to check in is all about `branch1.1`.

Comment: Are you trying to merge? Which way (master -> branch, or branch -> master)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Not merge, just want to check in the changes I made on `branch1.1`. Does `git push` only works for the `master`? I mean if I did an 'git commit' on `branch1.1`, do I need to make a 'git push' to make sure that these changes will be made on that branch? Or just 'git commit' will be enough.

Comment: Do you have a remote `branch1.1`? You can commit to `branch1.1`, and you can switch to `master`. You can `pull`, but what do you want to `push` to? If its the remote/master then you first need to merge to your local master.

Comment: I do have a `branch1.1`. When I do `git branch`, it shows: branch 1.1, master. I am working on `branch1.1`, and I use `git commit` to commit such changes of `branch1.1`. My question is how to push them to `branch1.1`. Because when I do `git push`, errors listed in the question is shown.

Comment: @Liquid: `git branch` shows your *local* branches, not the branches on the remote.  Use `git ls-remote` to see what's on the remote right now, or `git branch -r` to see what your local git has recorded as being on the remote as of the last time your git talked with the remote.

Comment: I do have a `branch1.1` for sure. @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `git push` without giving it any extra arguments, it will use your `push.default` setting to decide which branch(es) to attempt to push.

The "default `push.default`" in older versions of git is `matching`: if you have a branch named `branch1.1`, and the remote has a branch named `branch1.1`, git will add `branch1.1` to the list of things it believes you asked it to push.  If you have a branch named `master`, and the remote has a branch named `master`, git will *also* add `master` to the list of things it believes you asked it to push.

(If the remote *does not* have a `branch1.1`, your own git will *not* add `branch1.1` to the list of things to push.  I can't tell from your question whether your remote has a `branch1.1`.)

If you *don't* want to push `master`, you can:

- explicitly specify what to push: `git push origin branch1.1`<sup>1</sup>
- change your `push.default`
- upgrade your version of git to a newer version with a different default value for `push.default`

(this is not an exhaustive list, it just covers the basics).

Personally, I like to set my `push.default` to `nothing` which forces me to explicitly name which branch(es) I wish to push.  However, git 2.0 defaults to `simple`, which is probably the most useful for beginners.  To set your own default (across all repositories) to simple, use:

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

(see [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for details).

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that this "means" `git push origin branch1.1:branch1.1`, i.e., push from your local `branch1.1` to the remote's `branch1.1`, creating the branch on the remote if necessary.  This is how you can create the branch initially.

Note also that you do not have to use the same name in your git repository as on the remote.  For instance, you could `git push origin branch1.1:liquid-branch-1.1`.  It does, however, get confusing if you use different names; the `simple` setting enforces the "must have same name" restriction, to avoid this kind of confusion.  If you create a `liquid-branch-1.1` on the remote you will likely want to rename the branch in your local git.

Comment: seems that `git push origin branch1.1` is exactly what I want. I will accept this answer